# ASP.Net MVC - Entity Framework 6 sometimes creates duplicate records?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, transactions, entity-framework-6

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 application using EF6. I'm using Ninject for dependency injection.

I have the following code to add comments to a ticket. But sometimes it creating duplicate record. Why is is this happening and how can I fix?

So all in all I'm ending up with 3 comments being added as opposed to two with the user comments being duplicated - this is only happening occasionally.

```
 var ticket = _unitOfWork.TicketRepository.GetTicket(dto.TicketId);

 using (var transaction = _unitOfWork.BeginTransaction())
 {
       try
       {
             // Add user posted comment
             var comment = new Comment
             {
                TicketId = dto.TicketId,
                Comments = dto.Comments
             };

             ticket.AddComment(comment);

             // save changes
             _unitOfWork.Complete();

             // Add a system comment
             ticket.AddComment(new Comment                    
             {
                TicketId = dto.TicketId,
                Comments = "<b>System Comment:</b><br>Some auto comment"
             });

             _notificationService.Send(ticket, comment, User.Identity.GetUserId());

             // save changes
             _unitOfWork.Complete();

             // Commit
             transaction.Commit();

             return Ok(Mapper.Map<CommentDto>(_unitOfWork.CommentRepository.GetComment(comment.Id)));

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
            transaction.Rollback();

            return InternalServerError(ex);
       }

 }
```

These are the methods in my unitOfWork class:

```
 public void Complete()
 {
        _context.SaveChanges();
 }

 public DbContextTransaction BeginTransaction()
 {
        return _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
 }
```

This is the add comment method in my Ticket class:

```
 public void AddComment(Comment comment)
 {
        Comments.Add(comment);
 }
```

*** UPDATE ***

The only other thing I'm aware of that uses db context is a background job to send email which runs every minute using hangfire but doesn't use unitofwork - see my code below:

```
 [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
 public class EmailJob : IJob 
 {

    private readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private readonly IUserNotificationRepository _userNotificationRepository;
    private readonly INotificationMailer _notificationMailer;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public EmailJob()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        _userNotificationRepository = new UserNotificationRepository(_context);
        _notificationMailer = new NotificationMailer();
    }


    public EmailJob(IUserNotificationRepository userNotificationRepository,
        INotificationMailer notificationMailer)
    {
        _userNotificationRepository = userNotificationRepository;
        _notificationMailer = notificationMailer;
    }

    // Use for hangfire
    public void Execute()
    {
        SendMail(_logger);
    }

    private void SendMail(Logger logger)
    {
        // some mail sending code...

        // Persist changes back to database
         _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Any ideas chaps?

Comment: Who sets the timestamp? EF?

Comment: @cassandrad I meant the created date and comment is identical.

Comment: You have the same ticketId. EF distinguishes entities by id, so that looks like you are inserting and then updating the same record. Is TicketId  a primary key?

Comment: @cassandrad ticketid is a foreign key. A ticket can have multiple comments. Plus it's only inserting duplicates record occasionally.

Comment: Any chance the db context instance is shared and concurrently accessed by multiple threads?

Comment: @IvanStoev how would i troubleshoot that? I have the db context defined in request scope in ninject `kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();` The only other thing I'm aware of that uses db context is a background job to send email which runs every minute using hangfire but doesnt use unitofwork. Could that cause this kind of behavior - see my code above

Comment: SaveChanges is called twice. Every call adds duplicate records. Just call it once as within transaction everything will be saved at once.

Comment: @cassandrad no that is incorrect. Calling save changes twice doesn't persist the changes inside a transaction - calling transaction commit does that. Otherwise I'b be able to replicate the issue with every posted comment.

Comment: As I see, the background job creates its own context instance, so it should not be the issue. I have no idea how you can troubleshoot that. From your explanation, sounds like the first comment remains in `Added` state after `SaveChanges`. Or something happens after that. The problem is that as you said, it doesn't happen every time, you need to figure out what's the difference when it happens. But how you can do that, I don't know - try debugging, logging etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev when I create a new comment do i need to include `TicketId = dto.TicketId` before calling `ticket.AddComment(comment);` because `ticket.AddComment(comment)` should automatically add that relationship shouldn't it? e.g `var comment = new Comment  { Comments = dto.Comments             }; ticket.AddComment(comment);` should suffice?

Comment: Correct, you don't need to do that (and in some other scenarios, when the `ticket` is new and the final `Id` is not known yet, you shouldn't. Although this is not the case here.)

Comment: @IvanStoev so it make no difference in my case and probably not a factor in this unsual behaviour?

Comment: Correct, but can't say 100% - there are other factors which might eventually have impact - like inverse virtual navigation property in combination with lazy loading enabled. Still I believe under normal circumstances it should not happen, that's why I initially asked for multiple threads, because they usually cause unexpected behaviors on not thread safe class like db context. You could try removing it and see how it goes.